# change the queryset from a view in a filter

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-filter, drf-queryset

I would like to have default behaviour where queryset in a view returns records where publish_at date is less than some date. I also want to have boolean DRF filter that if set to true returns all the records no matter what publish_at date is.

views.py:

```
    queryset = ProjectNews.objects.exclude(publish_at__gte=timezone.now())
```

filters.py:

```
    from django_filters import rest_framework as filters
    class ProjectNewsFilterSet(filters.FilterSet):
        not_published = filters.BooleanFilter(
                            method='show_not_published_news'
                        )
        def show_not_published(self, queryset, name, value):
            if value:
                # queryset based on queryset from view
                # does not return all the records
                return queryset.all() 
            return queryset.exclude(publish_at__gte=timezone.now())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change queryset to:

`queryset = ProjectNews.objects.all()`

Than you filter queryset in your filter.

Comment: Yes, you are right. It is simpler than I thought. The only problem I have with this solution is how to get the Project ID. I did it using value from the request but I don't know if it is the right way?: 
        ProjectNews.objects.filter(               project=self.request.parser_context['kwargs']['parent_lookup_project'])

Comment: Could you show your view, I think you have Id there